# How to pass file path location in windows and call a post api using python code?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api'

files=[('file',('image.png',open('/C:/Users/Swarnitha/Downloads/image.png','rb'),'image/png'))]

#files = {"file":open('/C:/Users/Swarnitha/Downloads/image.png','rb')}


response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

In windows I am sending the path of the file like this. I am getting error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 66, in <module>
    ('file',('image.png',open('/C:/Users/Swarnitha/Downloads/image.png','rb'),'image/png'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/C:/Users/Swarnitha/Downloads/image.png'
```

Usually I use to run the same code in ubuntu and give file path from ubuntu software,it use to work.

Please give me solution for this

Comment: remove `/` from the start of the string as it signifies the root directory so you really are trying to access `'C:/C:/...'` (if `C:` is the root directory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953834/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the '/' to '\'.
Windows dosen't work with regular /

like :

`C:\\Users\\Swarnitha\\Downloads\\image.png`
or
`C:\Users\Swarnitha\Downloads\image.png`

Comment: tried not working ,getting file not found error

Comment: Maybe the file isn't there or the name/extension are not correct.

Comment: I got solution for my issue by passing the file location as /mnt/e/swarnitha/finaltesting.xlsx